# How use `unaccent` with full text search in django 1.10?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

We are working on a project and we are using `Django 1.10a1`, we're using django full text search with PostgreSQL but we need to use unaccent.

So, I have this code:

```
        search = 'Car'
        query_set = Article.objects.annotate(
            search=SearchVector(
                'content',
                'name'
                )
            ).filter(
            search__unaccent=search
        )
```

When we tried adding `unaccent` word after `search` the query doesn't work.
How can we get django full text search to work with postgress unaccent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the *unaccent* extension into your database:

```
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Create a new search configuration, based on an other one:

```
mydb=# CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_unaccent( COPY = french );
```

Insert the *unaccent* dictionary into your new search configuration:

```
mydb=# ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION french_unaccent
    ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
    WITH unaccent, french_stem;
```

Use this configuration in your Django query :

```
search = 'Car'
query_set = Article.objects.annotate(
                search=SearchVector('content','name', config='french_unaccent')
            ).filter(search=SearchQuery(search, config='french_unaccent')))
```

Comment: You can also install the extension directly from django as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#unaccentextension

Answer (score 1):

1. in your postgres db: `CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;`
2. add into INSTALLED_APPS: `"django.contrib.postgres"`
3. then: `.objects.filter(col__unaccent__icontains="Car")`

Comment: I didn't need to do #1

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
query_set.annotate(col_lower=Unaccent(Lower(col_name)))
```

Thanks.