# Using Unaccent in Django Model database function

Tags: python, django

I have the `unaccent` extension installed in Postgres and simple filters are working fine in my Django app, for example:

```py
q = 'hello'
queryset.filter(name__unaccent__startswith=q)
```

I'm now trying to annotate the queryset result with the search index:

```py
queryset.annotate(search_index=StrIndex(Lower('name'), Value(q)))
```

That works fine by itself for unaccented text, but I'm trying to figure out a way to apply UNACCENT to the name variable.  Essentially:

```sql
SELECT
  -- This is what I want!
  STRPOS(LOWER(UNACCENT(core_ingredient.name)::text), 'hello') AS search_index_unaccented,
  STRPOS(LOWER(core_ingredient.name), 'hello') AS search_index_basic
FROM
  -- ...
```

I've tried:

```py
# This has no effect, gives same query / result as above
queryset.annotate(search_index=StrIndex(Lower('name__unaccent'), Value(q)))
```

I've seen this answer:
[How use `unaccent` with full text search in django 1.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818492/how-use-unaccent-with-full-text-search-in-django-1-10) but feel like that shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After additional digging, I was able to just do this:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.lookups import Unaccent

queryset.annotate(search_index=StrIndex(Unaccent(Lower('name')), Value(q)))
```

Doesn't seem to be well documented in Django, but works as expected with SQL:

```sql
STRPOS(UNACCENT(LOWER("core_ingredient"."name")), 'hello') AS "search_index"
```